# Concatenating two strings in tcl

Tags: string, tcl, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate two strings in tcl and then trim the concatenated string if there is any unwanted character like `'_'`. The strings are stored in tcl variables and the problem I am facing is that I need to concatenate these two strings like `"$str1_$str2"`. Basically join two strings with an `'_'` in between them. I found the way to do it as below.

```
    set str1 "mystring1";  #string 1
    set str2 "mystring2";  #string 2. This string could be Empty String as well.

    set outString [append outString "_" $str2];
    set outString [string trimright '_'];
```

This gives me the value of outString as below :

```
    puts $outString;  
    mystring1_mystring2    #if $str2 is not empty
    mystring1              #if $str2 is empty.
```

I am looking for a more optimized way to achieve my task. I tried to simply join the two strings like

```
    set outString "$str1_$str2"
```

But I get the error as "No such variable as $str1_" since '_' underscore can be part of variable name.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When interpolating a variable into a string, you can use curly braces to protect the variable name.

```
set str1 "mystring1";
set str2 "mystring2";
set outString "${str1}_${str2}"
```

(The same syntax works in shell scripts, in Perl, and probably in other scripting languages.)

But I wouldn't count on this being "more optimized" that calling `append`. It's easier to read, which IMHO is a good enough reason to do it this way, but don't assume it's faster until you've measured it.

Reference: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12

Comment: Which, the braces? That's in [Tcl(n)](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12).